Remix , Vite .Import error Unexpected token 'export'
I get this error
[vite] Internal server error: [vite] Named export 'findIndex' not found. The requested module 'lodash' is a CommonJS module
I tried all I see online and cannot solve this issue. This is foundational as I need to use this library.
This is my vite:
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port: 3000,
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ["lodash","@commercelayer/react-components"]
    },
   /* ssr: {
        noExternal: ["@commercelayer/react-components", "lodash"]
    },*/
    plugins: [
        //vitePluginRequire,
        //commonjs(),
        nodePolyfills(),
        remixDevTools(),
        remix({
            future: {
                v3_fetcherPersist: true,
                v3_relativeSplatPath: true,
                v3_throwAbortReason: true,
            },
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true, // Enables source maps
        commonjsOptions: {
            //include: [/node_modules/],
            transformMixedEsModules: true,
        },
    },
});

I have followed this solutions: https://www.dhiwise.com/post/how-to-troubleshoot-require-is-not-defined-issue-in-vite
